# Evaluate $\binom{n}{1} + 2\binom{n}{2} + 3 \binom{n}{3}+...+ n \binom{n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

Evaluate  $$\binom{n}{1} + 2\binom{n}{2} + 3 \binom{n}{3}+...+ n \binom{n}{n}$$

My attempt : I know  $(a+b) ^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k}b^k$

But here Im confuse how to evaluate and im not able to proceed further.

Comment: did you mean $2\binom n2$ (to fit the pattern)?

Comment: Usually a good starting place is to compute the expression for small $n$.  Perhaps a pattern emerges.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yaa thanks u

Comment: @jasmine hint: binomial theorem with a bit of calculus